# Why is moving a vertex messing up my mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I am doing a lesson from the Blender Guru (Making a donut).
When I move a part of the icing, my mesh gets totally messed up.

[image: Moving a vertec]

The icing had a bit of sculpting. I made it a bit thicker.
Would it be better to move the vertex in position and than do the sculpting?

Comment: you've enabled the snap option, it makes the vertices your moving snap to the surface of the other object

Comment: @moonboots You where right. That did solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You've enabled the snap option, it makes the vertices your moving snap to the surface of the other object, disable it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I did the tutorial I had the same problem. I think I solved it by rotating it along one axis.

See if that makes a difference.

Comment: You have to do it in the x axis

Comment: I think moonboots comment is correct.

Comment: Yes, I didn’t notice the snap option